# Как создавать новые виджеты через функцию в PyQt?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qlayout

Необходимо чтобы создавался новый элемент по нажатию кнопки, например, новая кнопка.

Могут ли создаваться новые элементы вне основной функции `setupUI`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(600, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100,100,100,100))
        self.but.setStyleSheet('background-color:blue')
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.click)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def click(self):
        self.but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200,200,100,100))
        self.but2.setStyleSheet('background-color:red')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: могут, только используй сетки для их рамещения

Comment: почему они не могут принадлежать centralwidget?

Comment: может и могут, просто обычно я через сетки строю интерфейс. квадратная кнопка висящая хз где - не вау)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, если вы не и используете менеджеры компоновки и вы создаете новый виджет, то вам надо показывает этот новый виджет.

Абсолютное позиционирование - это плохая практика. 
Советую вам ознакомиться с
[**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) - cистема компоновки Qt предоставляет простой и мощный способ автоматического размещения дочерних виджетов внутри виджета, чтобы убедиться, что они эффективно используют доступное пространство...

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

А теперь почувствуйте разницу:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(600, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.but.setStyleSheet('background-color:blue')

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
 

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        scrollArea  = QtWidgets.QScrollArea() 
        main_layout.addWidget(scrollArea)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)         
        
        self.row = 1
        self.column = 1
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but, self.row, self.column)
        
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.clicked_but)

    def clicked_but(self):
        self.row += 1
        self.column += 1        
        new_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        new_but.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        new_but.setStyleSheet('background-color:red')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(new_but, self.row, self.column)
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Наверное Вы забыли вызвать метод `show()`

```
self.but2.show()
```